# Is there histo function in MATLAB?

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

histo function in MATLAB, does anyone knows what it does? histo(image) what does this return?

I found in google but there I couldnt find any predefined function in MATLAB. Is there some new includes in Latest MATLAB. If anyone knows please explain what is happening below.

`hist=histo(image);
pdf=hist/sum(hist);
t_new=round(sum(pdf.*[0:255]));`

Comment: likely a custom made function. Can you show us where on the internets you found this?

Comment: I found the function stored in a folder. I was looking at different folder thought it is Toolbox function. Can you please explain what this does sum(pdf.*[0:255]). I am new to MATLAB.

Comment: it's not a basic Matlab function, so you'll need to peruse the code to figure out what it does. pdf.*[0:255] multiplies every element of the pdf array by 1, 2, 3, 4... 255, respectively. `sum` then adds them up.

Comment: by using variable hist you override the built-in matlab function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`histo()` is probably a user-defined function that counts image historgram. You can use built-in Matlab function `hist()` instead:

```
 n = hist(image)
```

Read more:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB command for calculating image histogram is [`imhist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html)

It is used as

```
hist = imhist(image);
```